# read.table returns extra stuff on last column

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read the table from the following URL:

```
url <- 'http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/introTS/m-ge3dx-4011.txt'
da <- read.table(url, header = TRUE, fill=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
```

I can look at the data using `head`:

```
> head(da)
      date        ge        vw        ew        sp
1 19400131 -0.061920 -0.024020 -0.019978 -0.035228
2 19400229 -0.009901  0.013664  0.029733  0.006639
3 19400330  0.049333  0.018939  0.026168  0.009893
4 19400430 -0.041667  0.001196  0.013115 -0.004898
5 19400531 -0.197324 -0.220314 -0.269754 -0.239541
6 19400629  0.061667  0.066664  0.066550  0.076591
```

This works fine for the first 4 columns, for example, I can look at the column `ew`

```
> head(da$ew)
[1] -0.019978  0.029733  0.026168  0.013115 -0.269754  0.066550
```

but when I try to access the last one, I get some extra output which is not in the txt file.

```
> head(da$sp)
[1] -0.035228 0.006639  0.009893  -0.004898 -0.239541 0.076591 
859 Levels: -0.000060 -0.000143 -0.000180 -0.000320 -0.000659 -0.000815 ... 0.163047
```

How do I get rid of the extra output? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is representation of a factor.

```
> str(da)
'data.frame':   861 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date: int  19400131 19400229 19400330 19400430 19400531 19400629 19400731 19400831 19400930 19401031 ...
 $ ge  : num  -0.0619 -0.0099 0.0493 -0.0417 -0.1973 ...
 $ vw  : num  -0.024 0.0137 0.0189 0.0012 -0.2203 ...
 $ ew  : num  -0.02 0.0297 0.0262 0.0131 -0.2698 ...
 $ sp  : Factor w/ 859 levels "-0.000060","-0.000143",..: 226 411 445 42 353 828 613 585 441 684 ...
```

Row 58 has a dot instead of a number. This is sufficient information for R to handle the variable as a factor. Once you change the dot to NA or fix the error, you will be able to read in the data fine.

Another option would be to change the point to something meaningful after the data has been read in, and coercing to numeric afterwards. The following statement will coerce . to NA.

```
da$sp <- as.numeric(as.character(da$sp))
> str(da)
'data.frame':   861 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date: int  19400131 19400229 19400330 19400430 19400531 19400629 19400731 19400831 19400930 19401031 ...
 $ ge  : num  -0.0619 -0.0099 0.0493 -0.0417 -0.1973 ...
 $ vw  : num  -0.024 0.0137 0.0189 0.0012 -0.2203 ...
 $ ew  : num  -0.02 0.0297 0.0262 0.0131 -0.2698 ...
 $ sp  : num  -0.03523 0.00664 0.00989 -0.0049 -0.23954 ...
```